# Using reflection to add properties

Tags: swift

In Swift 2.1, I am trying to use reflection in order to add cases generated from a text file to an enum at compile time.

Here is the enum wrapper:

```
enum Kind : Int { 

}
```

Using C/++ I could just use this macro:

```
#define X(value, left, right) \
  value##Left = left, value##Right = right,
```

How can I get similar result in Swift?

Comment: Why not just a dictionary? Adding properties to a type at runtime would break the type safety that Swift is build around and I would not count on this being added, ever.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's an enum type. I don't think it would break type safety if I were to add at runtime time to an enum, right?

Comment: Do you want to add a `case` ? That is impossible and it would break the type system. Not all instances of the same type would have the same properties.

Comment: @RMenke I believe OP wants an [X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) equivalent in Swift.

Comment: are you mixing up runtime and compile time? reflection vs. preprocessor!? please explain what you mean/want

Comment: Preprocessor as in C macros would be ideal. However, beside generating code with some python scripts, what are my options beside doing it at runtime with some reflection mechanism that I am trying to figure out?

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor directives are deliberately cut down to a very bare minimum in Swift.  Even if technically possible, your particular case would go quite against Swift philosophy in respect of `enum`s, as this philosopy requires that `switch` statements on enumerations are *exhaustive*, that is, cover *all* possible `case`s.

Now, if you would be able to dynamically fill up the `enum`'s cases from some file, then how would compiler be able to ensure exhaustiveness?  Opting out to use `default:` cases all over the program would basically throw the whole Swift's idea of `enum` safety right into the window.

If you stick with Swift then you are probably better off with dictionary as @RMenke suggests.